# pass parameter to the server using datatable url property in ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm using data tables and on initialization inside ajax request I'm setting url using data- attribute

```
...
 "ajax": {
            "url": $('#mypage').data('source'),
            "type": "GET",
}...
```

url embeded in page looks like this

```
 <divid="mypage" data-source=@Url.Action("CalculateSomething")>
 ...
</dv>
```

On server side I'm expecting parameter someId

```
public JsonResult CalculateSomething(int someId)
{
}
```

my question is:

> how can I pass parameter to the server using datatable url property in
>   above ajax call?

**update**
Parameter will come as a value from drop down element inside javascript like

```
var someId = $('#mydropdown').val();
```

Comment: from where the parameter will come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways for this, one is you can concatenate in the url like:

```
 "ajax": {
            "url": $('#mypage').data('source')+"someId="+id,
            "type": "GET",
}
```

another way is to use data property of ajax :

```
"ajax": {
            "url": $('#mypage').data('source')+"someId=123",
            "type": "GET",
            "data": function (data) {

                            data.someId= 123;

                        }
}
```

Comment: data property it is :)

Answer (score 1):

Check documantation on [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). For params you can use `data` property. Like this:

```
 url: function(e) { return $('#mypage').data('source'); },
 type: "GET",
 data:
     {
         someId: function(e) { return $('#mydropdown').val(); }, //here is your param
     },
 dataType: "json", //it's better to declare datatype, becouse you using JsonResult in your controller response.
```